# How to vertical center content with picture on a standout beamer slide?

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer slide like this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[standout]
    Test!
    
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.jpg}
        \caption*{A Photo}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Because the image `test.jpg` is in portrait layout,
it does not occupies the full height of the slide.
Thus the content is vertically aligned at the topic of the slide.
How can I make everything vertically aligned in the center?

Comment: Not everyone knows which `beamer` theme(s) define(s) the `standout` option, so please post a _complete_ code.

Comment: Since a beamer figure is just a box with captions, try adding `\vspace*{\fill}` or some variant above and below it.  `\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\linewidth}{\begin{figure}...}` might work too.